# Let the author of the question highlight bits and pieces from answers

Tags: answers, accepted-answer, discussion

Could you let the author of a question **highlight** bits and pieces from one or more answers? This is

- to show **why** he/she chose this answer
- to highlight good points/**ideas** from other answers

Or let him/her make some kind of **summary** or even the summary could be worked out collectively.

Comment: I had in mind more visual way of highlighting ...

Answer (score 9):

The question asker can already do this in a number of different ways:

1. answer the question themselves, and synthesize the best parts of the existing answers in their own answer, wiki style (should be community wiki, and sources should be attributed)
2. edit the question with a summary at the bottom, indicating what the author feels is the best "synthesized" answer
3. accept an answer, then edit it to taste (ideally as a separate section below the original answer)
4. do nothing, let the vote order determine the best responses

Comment: It's all OK, but it's better when a question has a de jure summary. The flag, that the question has official summary, should be appear on the question list even. "Self-answer as accepted answer" looks so self-polishing and credit-hunting.

Comment: how can I edit accepted answer??